# ANDROID: How to use outlinedbox as a background for linearlayout?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I would like to ask how to implement as a background for my linear layout the functionality of outlinebox (textinputlayout) look like this,

[image]

Comment: this thing can be done but you cannot add textview.

Comment: Have a look to the material design library